# jQuery datepicker onSelect Pass Variable to Update Selection List

Tags: jquery, datepicker, onselect

I have the following code thus far

```
<script>      
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker( {
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function(date) {
            $("#eventoutput").empty()
            $.ajax({        
            url: 'getevents.php', data: "pickdate=2014-04-06", dataType: 'json',  success: function(rows)
            {
                for (var i in rows)
                    {
                      var row = rows[i];          

                      var eventtitle = row[0];
                      $('#eventoutput').append("<option value=\""+eventtitle+"\">"+eventtitle+"</option>");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Where the date is currently hardcoded (2014-04-06), I would like to pass the value/date selected in the format (yyyy-mm-dd).

I'm not sure of the appropriate syntax. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use that `date` variable passed in the `onSelect` function

```
onSelect: function(date) {
            $("#eventoutput").empty()
            $.ajax({        
            url: 'getevents.php', data: "pickdate="+date, dataType: 'json',  success: function(rows)
                {
                    ......
                    ......
                }
            });
}
```

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/1514/